# HTML video tag is not tracking in Google Analytics 4 if we don't have youtube URL

Tags: google-analytics-4

I am trying to track html video tag in Google Analytics 4. I have added the tracking code on the website. It is tracking the other links (.pdf etc)

It is tracking the video under iframe embedded with youtube link with extra parameter  **?enablejsapi=1**:-

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ly-IHQhX4DU?enablejsapi=1" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Even when I am  trying to add https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ly-IHQhX4DU?enablejsapi=1 in video component it is tracking in GA4. However when I am trying to add .mp4 video on website. It is not tracking.

`<video width="320" height="240" controls> <source src="~/video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support the video tag. </video>`

I am not using Google tag manager. I am using only GA4 to track the video. Could someone assist me on this.

Thanks in advance